# Use ListView horizontal like Tabview with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, tabview, horizontallistview

I'm looking for a tutorial on using a horizontal ListView that behaves like a Tabview, ie displaying the link on the same screen.
Some links to propose?
thanks

[image]

Comment: How about using default tabBar?

Comment: Indeed, but I want total control over the formatting, such as the number of links that must be large, the size of the Cards, the spacing, etc. And for the fun of the challenge!!!

Answer (score 0):

Tab child can others widget too, use `height` on `Tab` and `isScrollable:true` on `TabBar`

```dart
class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabBarDemo({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                    height: 100, // height
                    icon: Card(
                      child: Container(
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    )),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            title: const Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: const TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

more about [tabs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/tabs)

And using PageView & ListView, it will be

```dart
class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabBarDemo({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PageController controller = PageController();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 100, //tab item height
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  controller.animateToPage(index,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                      curve: Curves.bounceIn);
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Card(
                    child: Text("tab $index"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: PageView.builder(
              controller: controller,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text("$index"),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also you can check CustomScrollView.

Comment: Yes, here it is, the second method... I spent the afternoon trying to code the listview builder without being able to display the corresponding widget, I will just have to create a list to call the widget of the page corresponding to the card selected... Too strong, thanks

Comment: glad to help, also test 1st one and select the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

run this example and you will get the whole idea :

```
class ListTapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListTapPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ListTapPage> createState() => _ListTapPageState();
}

class _ListTapPageState extends State<ListTapPage> {

  List<Widget> pages = [const Center(child: Text("one")),const Center(child: Text("two")),const Center(child: Text("three"),)];
  List<String> names = ["one","two","three"];
  List<Color> colors = [Colors.red,Colors.blue,Colors.yellow];
  int _index = 0 ;

  void changeIndex({required int num}){
    setState((){
      _index = num;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(top: 0,right: 0,left: 0,bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 100,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: 3,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap:()=>changeIndex(num: index) ,
                          child: Container(alignment: Alignment.center,width: 200,height: 50,color: colors[index],child: Text(names[index])),
                        );
                        },
                    ),
                  )
              ),
              Positioned(
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.30,
                  child: pages[_index]
              ),
            ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

- just return this widget in the material app ,see the result and look at the code , you will understand , it's a simple demo.

Comment: Thank you also for this method, you both gave me the idea in place and helped me to move forward in my learning and project.
thank you